# How to convert java ArrayList to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList created like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();

        list1.add(0, 5);
        list1.add(1, 3.5);
        list1.add(2, 10);

    }
}
```

I am trying to create an array from it, using the `toArray` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();

        list1.add(0, 5);
        list1.add(1, 3.5);
        list1.add(2, 10);

        Double[] list2 = list1.toArray(new Double[list1.size()]);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting an error:

> (Error:(16, 39) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] ).

So I tried to cast the right side to double:

```
Double[] list2 = (Double[]) list1.toArray(new Double[list1.size()])
```

This time i am getting Exception in thread "main". I also tried to declare my ArrayList as double from beginning:

```
ArrayList<double> list1 = new ArrayList()<double>
```

With no success. How to do it properly? I know that my problem is probably something very basic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java?rq=1

Comment: The correct syntax is `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: You can`t put primitive type into List or any Collection. Generic classes only work with objects and don't support primitives. Use wrapper class [instead](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wrapper-classes).

Comment: @StephenC Actually it will solve the problem, I just tested this. Ideally, you would call toArray with `new Double[0]` but this should work fine in this case.

Comment: @Minn Only that change wouldn't let above code to compile. You still need to change `list1.add(0, 5);` to `list1.add(0, 5.0);` otherwise to place `5` to internal `Object[]` array it would be wrapped in `Intger` object which can't be placed in `Double[]` array.

Comment: @Pshemo yes that is indeed correct. I was just pointing out that the usage of `toArray` is not the problem.

Comment: I am still not getting it. I tried the String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]) solution, but id does not work form my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a number of things wrong:

1. `ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();` is incorrect because you are using a raw type.  You should have gotten a compiler warning for that.
2. Given the previous `list1.add(0, 5)` is incorrect.  The `5` will be boxed as an `Integer` because that compiler doesn't know that the list is only supposed to contain `Double` values.
3. You were getting this:

   ```
   (Error:(16, 39) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] ).
   ```

   because you must have done something like this:

   ```
   Double[] list2 = list1.toArray();
   ```

   You appear to have corrected that in the code that you posted.  But the no-args `toArray` method returns an `Object[]` containing the list content.
4. `ArrayList<double> list1 = new ArrayList()<double>` is incorrect because you cannot use a primitive type as a generic type parameter, and because the syntax on the RHS is wrong.

   The correct version is `ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>();` with an empty diamond.

Surprisingly, the best (most efficient) way to code the `toArray` is:

```
Double[] list2 = list1.toArray(new Double[0]);
```

Apparently, the implementation is able to initialize the array faster if it allocates it itself.  (Or so I have heard ...)